# Copy a file via drag and drop to `/usr/local`

Tags: root, root-filesystem

I have a file `mathpass` (without a file ending `.*`) in `/home/patrick/Documents` and want to copy it via drag and drop to `/usr/local`.

If I do so, a message `Access denied. Could not write to.` appears.
What is the problem? I already tried `sudo su` in both directories.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I already tried sudo su in both directories.'?

Comment: Depending on the files, often it is better to put such files in own home. Checkout e.g. `~/bin/` , `~/lib/`, `~/include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to drag and drop it means you are doing it from a GUI file explorer. Those, as most other programs run unprivileged by default, meaning that the program has no permissions to write on /usr/local .

The best approach is to simply open a terminal and write:

```
sudo cp /home/patrick/Documents/mathpass /usr/local
```